# lxml find does not return element

Tags: python, lxml

I'm trying to parse and grab an element from an xml-file with lxml.

```
<root> 
<a>
<b>
</root>

print(root.find("a")) 
--- None
for child in root:
  print child
--- a
--- b
```

I'm so confused. Why does find not return the element for me?
I'm useing lxml 4.3.3 and im certain it's installed correctly.

Comment: That's not valid XML. All XML tags must be closed, either with a closing tag or a self-closing tag. A proper validating XML parser should reject it.

Comment: What happens if you change to `<a/> <b/>`?

Comment: sorry, I forgot the closing in the transkription. I can assure you, that the file I'm trying to process is completly valid and wellformed. Thanks.

Comment: @sanlalala, and _I_ can assure _you_ that we aren't going to guess which errors are relevant and which are typos. Please [edit] your question and make sure that the code you share _exactly_ reflects your real code. We need a [mcve]. While you're at it, please show us how you create `root`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it. I was processing a file that referenced a Schema at the beginning and this seemed to confuse lxml. Therefore I could access the structure, root[0] etc., but not do basic operations like search for a tagname.